# SSD not working anymore and windows not opening

Tags: windows-10, data-recovery, ssd, recovery, hard-drive

Windows suddenly stopped working when I connected the HDD with rack on my laptop. I’ve tried almost everything, so later on I have discovered after reinstalling the HDD and placing the SSD in the rack that the SSD is not initialized and also is 100% free. After that I tried to recover the files from the SSD because I've lost sensitive information and a lot of photos from the past years, but nothing worked.

What happened and what solutions do I have? Is the SSD broken somehow?

Last error when I'm trying to initialize:

[image]

My laptop has HDD from the factory, but due to some technical reasons I bought an SSD and installed it in the original place of the HDD and also a rack which means I connected the external HDD to access some information I needed. After a few months, I tried to connect again the external HDD to check something, but didn't work and the laptop froze. I made some changes in the BIOS trying to start again the windows, but nothing worked as I said, and constantly got this message: *Reboot and select proper boot device or insert boot media in selected boot device*.

Error:

[image: Click to see the error]

The rack I'm using and the SSD:

[image: rack]

[image: SSD]

Important note: when I`m trying to scan the SSD any data with recovery applications, I always receive the same error *to reconnect the drive* as in images.

[image: ERRORS]

Comment: What do you mean by "with rack"? When you tried to use the SSD, was it connected precisely the same way it was back when it was working?

Comment: My laptop has HDD from factory, but due to some technical reasons I bought SSD and installed it in the original place of the HDD and also a "RACK" which means I connected the external HDD to access some information I needed. After a few months, I tried to connect again the external HDD to check something, but didn`t work and the laptop freezed. I made some changes in the BIOS trying to start again the windows, but nothing worked as I said, and constantly got this message: "Reboot and select proper boot device or insert boot media in selected boot device".

Comment: We might be able to help you, but you are still giving very little detail on exactly what happened. You say "didn't work and the laptop freezed". That's pretty vague. Did the laptop boot? Did it freeze when you connected the external drive? Did you connect using USB? Do you remember what you changed in the BIOS? Is the SSD a SATA drive? What do you mean by "I'm trying to initialize"? If you want to save the data on the disk, why are you trying to initialize it?

Comment: Also, if the data on the SSD is really important, you need to 100% stop what you're doing and work on preserving the data. That means connecting the SSD to a known good system with known good adapters/cables/whatever, and making a byte-for-byte image of it, if possible. Anything you try to do other than that risks corrupting the data on the SSD further. You have no business attempting to boot from it while you're still trying to save the data on it. That's reckless.

Comment: So, my laptop started always normally till I connected the HDD with that "rack" I was talking about. I dunno what I changed in the BIOS because it was a few weeks ago, but yes, trying to find a solution I made some changes in the BIOS. Now, I replaced again the SSD already installed and not bootable with the HDD  and the SSD is connected with that "rack", figuring out what happened and why it`s unitialized, unpartitioned etc. Yes, it is SATA drive. And trying to initialize was a mistake, as you said, I need the data from the disk. I`m happy that didn`t work.

Comment: Can you give us the make and model of both the SSD and the rack? I have a few theories but need to narrow things down a bit. Again though, I strongly suggest you shift all efforts to imaging the SSD and not trying to do anything else if you really want to preserve the data on it. Anything that you do that might write to the SSD risks corrupting the data on it.

Comment: I uploaded the images with the SSD and the rack, see the original question please.

Comment: Important note: when I`m trying to scan for any data on the SSD with recovery applications, I always receive the same error to reconnect the drive.

Comment: The empty disk can not be cloned. I tried.

Comment: So what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Cyclic Redundancy Check is an error-detecting code used for data verification. When you get this error message, it means there is something wrong with the files or the hard drive.

Basically either your files or the drive itself has an error.

If you still want the drive, you may have to just format it (be warned formatting the drive will permanently delete all your data on the drive)

Comment: If you look at the screenshot posted you will see the drive with the error has no allocated partitions. You cannot `chkdsk` a drive with no partitions allocated in this way

Comment: @ChrisRogers ah my bad, didn’t see the last part,the rest of the info is still useful so I’ll just edit that last part out. Thanks for noticing !

Comment: You've jumped to a conclusion with insufficient evidence, IMO. For example, the CRC errors could be coming from using a damaged (or poor quality) SATA cable. We don't know what the OP has changed.

Comment: I need that data from the SSD, so I`m trying to find a solution to recover its files.

Answer (score 0):

As @ItsMeNaira points out,

> Cyclic Redundancy Check is an error-detecting code used for data verification. When you get this error message, it means there is something wrong with the files or the hard drive.

As you are using the harddrive externally to the computer, it can also mean problems with the USB lead, USB header in your computer or "rack" as you call it. I call it a harddrive enclosure.

$3.55 is very cheap for a harddrive enclosure. Are you sure the build quality  is good?

You said it worked in the past. Did you switch the laptop off **or** use the "safely remove device" function before unplugging the harddrive from the laptop? If not, you may have corrupted the drive.

If this is not the case, check the following:

- **The enclosure is a USB 3 enclosure. Is it connected to a USB 3 connection on the computer.**
  Although USB 3 is **normally** a backwards compatible connection, USB 3 harddrive enclosures often need a USB 3 connection because it needs the extra pins provided for power supply. USB 2 enclosures have a separate power supply lead.
- **Try the drive in another USB 3 connection if you have one.** 
  If it works ok then the previous USB 3 connector is faulty.
- **Take the harddrive out of the enclosure and re-introduce it to the computer's motherboard.**
  If you can use the drive after that, the enclosure is at fault. Ditch the enclosure and get another one you can trust to be of a good build quality.

One problem with laptops though is that most only come with one harddrive connection on the motherboard. If this is the case and the SSD no longer has an active Windows partition, you will need to connect the harddrive to a laptop with a second internal harddrive connection or a PC as you need to have an active Windows partition to boot your computer.

If neither work, there is only one way I know to try and sort the problem out, and @ItsMeNaira pointed to it (use `chkdsk`), but you need to do it in a different way **and you need the harddrive connected to the motherboard with an active Windows partition**.

- Keep the SSD connected to the motherboard
- Open Disk Management (diskmgmt.msc)
- Right-click on the volume you want to scan.
- Select "Properties"
- Go to the "Security" tab.
- Copy the "Object name" string displayed at the top of the tab
- Open a UAC-elevated command prompt
- Type `chkdsk /f`
- Paste-in the string you copied in step 5
- Remove the trailing slash
- Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

This will try and fix the error. If the files don't return and file recovery tools don't help with the drive connected to the motherboard, you have unfortunately lost your files and you will need to allocate partitions and format the drive to use it.

**!!!!------WARNING------!!!!**

If the files are back, be warned that the enclosure could still have affected the drive. Create a backup of your files or test the enclosure for a good while with a non-critical harddrive (one you don't mind being corrupted).

Comment: The problem is that I don`t have properties for that disk. (the SSD)

Comment: @ReflexRoland - My edit should help now

Comment: I unplugged the SSD from motherboard and switched with the HDD because the windows didn`t boot. So I decided to connect with the enclosure and try at least to recover the files from the SSD. I don`t have "Security" tab from your method :(.

Comment: @ReflexRoland - See my further edit. As far as I know you cannot run chkdsk on an external harddrive which has a Cyclic Redundancy Check error. You will need to reconnect it to a computer motherboard which has a harddrive with an active Windows partition.

Comment: I think we misunderstood. I had windows installed on the SSD and now I`m running with an active Windows partition as well because the HDD is installed in his place as it was from fabric. The only reason I`ve connected the HDD again is that I wanted to try to solve the problem with the SSD.

Comment: OK @ReflexRoland. If you are supposed to have an active Windows partition on the SSD and it doesn't boot, then your SSD needs to be connected with a second drive (which has an active Windows partition) on the same motherboard to carry out a `chkdsk`. Otherwise you cannot fix the error and the only option left would be to format and lose your files which you don't want. This highlights the reason for maintaining up-to-date backups of important files.

Comment: I searched on Google and found out that it is possible to run chkdsk on an external harddrive. But the problem is that it is not partitioned, it didn`t have any letter. I think I need to initialize the disk first, but I`m afraid to lose all my data.

Comment: Running `chkdsk` is a terrible idea. It's irreversible and is a write operation that may do further damage.

Answer (score -1):

> > Cyclic Redundancy Check is an error-detecting code used for data verification. When you get this error message, it means there is something wrong with the files or the hard drive.
> >
> > Basically either your files or the drive itself has an error.

It is as ItsMeNaira said (I gave her an upvote).

The fact that this drive gives a CRC error means that something has gone completely wrong.  If you will continue to use this drive (after a format), you should keep a close watch on its functioning. At least for some time, do not store any critical data on it and make very sure you keep backups.

For recovery of files from bad drives, you use in general specialized software. Most are Linux-based. I have had some positive experiences with `ddrescue` and `photorec`, but that was all spinning rust and not ssd.

If you want to recover files, you must **not** do checkdisks, or use any tool that writes to the disk. Put yourself in the mindset that you want to recover data. Whether you can use the disk again later on is for after the recovery.

What I would do:

- buy an USB disk that is bigger than the SSD
- get a live edition of a Linux with `ddrescue` and `photorec`
- use `ddrescue` to create an image file from the SSD on the new USB disk
- use `photorec` on the copied image
- keep the broken drive as-is, so I can get a new image from it if required.